# Chemical Potential of Ideal Fermi Gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

In Wikipedia's article on [Fermi Gases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas), they have the following equation for the chemical potential:

> $$\mu = E_0 + E_F \left[ 1- \frac{\pi ^2}{12} \left(\frac{kT}{E_F}\right) ^2 - \frac{\pi^4}{80} \left(\frac{kT}{E_F}\right)^4 + \cdots \right]$$
>   where $E_0$ is the potential energy per particle, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature.

I don't understand how they get the third term, particularly the 1/80 factor. I've often seen this equation expressed just to the tau^2 term, and I understand how to get the 1/12 factor from a binomial expansion of
$$\left( 1 + \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} \left(\frac{\tau}{E}\right)^{2}\right)^{-2/3} $$

However, I've tried continuing the binomial expansion and cannot figure out why the factor is 1/80.

Comment: Sorry about the erroneous edit - our bad. (+1 btw :)

Comment: No worries; I should've written it in Latek to start. Unfortunately I had somewhere I needed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not sure how you obtained the last expression. The standard Sommerfeld expansion (for details, see e.g. Ashcroft & Mermin) gives a slightly different result, which is
$$
E_{F} \approx \mu\left[1+\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{\mu}\right)^{2}\,\right]^{2/3} \approx \mu\left[1+\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{\mu}\right)^{2}\right]
$$
to leading non-trivial order in $k_{B}T/\mu$, i.e., $O\big((k_{B}T/\mu)^{2}\big)$.
(I have set $E_{0}=0$ in the expression from Wikipedia.)

We can invert this relation by substituting  $\mu = E_{F}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + \cdots \right]$ into the above. That is,

$$
E_{F} = E_{F}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + \cdots \right]\left\{1+\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{E_{F}}\right)^{2}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + \cdots\right]^{-2}\right\}.
$$

Comparing the zeroth order terms in $k_{B}T/E_{F}$ on both sides of the above equation, we simply obtain $E_{F}=E_{F}$. Comparing the second order terms, we have $0 = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12} + c_{2}$. Hence

$$
\mu = E_{F}\left[1-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{E_{F}}\right)^{2}\right]
$$
up to $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}\Big)$.

To determine the next-order correction to $\mu$, you should include one higher order term in the Sommerfeld expansion, which gives

$$
E_{F} \approx \mu\left[1+\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{\mu}\right)^{2}+\frac{7\pi^{4}}{640}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{\mu}\right)^{4}\,\right]^{2/3}.
$$

Expanding this up to $O\big((k_{B}T/\mu)^{4}\big)$, then substituting $\mu = E_{F}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + c_{4} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{4}+\cdots\right]$ (where we have already determined $c_{2}$ before) into it, and then matching the coefficients of both sides up to $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{4}\Big)$ will lead to the desired result.

Comment: Where does $\mu = E_{F}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}\right]$ come from?

Comment: I'm expanding $\mu/E_{F}$ in powers of a small quantity $k_{B}T/E_{F}$, and we know that it is equal to one at zeroth order because $E_{F}=\mu$ at $T=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not quite following. I'm trying to repeat your analysis and get to $\mu = E_{F} \left[1 - \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\left(\frac{k_{B}T}{E_{F}}\right)^{2}\right]$, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Substitute $\mu = E_{F}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + \cdots \right]$ into $E_{F} = \mu \left[1 + \frac{\pi^{2}}{12} \left(\frac{k_{B}T}{\mu}\right)^{2} \right]$ and match the coefficient of both sides up to  $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}\Big)$.

Comment: I tried that, and I didn't achieve anything. What is $O\big((k_{B}T/\mu)^{2}\big)$?

Comment: $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}\Big)$ means second order in $k_{B}T/E_{F}$.

Comment: Ok, I've tried the substitution numerous times and it doesn't seem to go anywhere - I never get $ C = -\pi^2/12$. And if I were just matching up coefficients, wouldn't I say that $C = \pi^2/8$?

Comment: I'll add the details.

Comment: But for the second order terms, don't we get $0 = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\left[1 + c_{2} (k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2} + \cdots\right]^{-2} + c_{2}$?

Comment: $\left[1+c_{2}(k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}+\cdots\right]^{-2} = 1 - 2c_{2}(k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}+\cdots \approx 1$. We neglect the term proportional to $(k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}$ (as well as higher-order terms) here because it contributes to $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{4}\Big)$ rather than $O\Big((k_{B}T/E_{F})^{2}\Big)$ which we are considering now.

Comment: Ok.... If you say so. This level of math just goes right over my head. All of the estimations and approximations and when we can/can't/do/don't ignore terms makes no sense to me.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is nothing ad hoc in what I've done. I'm expanding both sides in powers of some parameter ($k_{B}T/E_{F}$ in this case) and equating the coefficients order by order.

Comment: So I tried doing the same analysis as above for the 2nd power terms, and I got $0 = C_{1} + \pi^2/12 , 0 = C_{2} + 7\pi^4/960 + C_{1}\pi^2/12$. I got $C_{1} = -\pi^2/12$ again, but also $C_{2} = -\pi^4/2880$, but I thought the right answer was $C_{2} = -\pi^4/80$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have done. Could you write it as an answer but not as a comment?

Comment: How about we go in one of the chatrooms? I made one called 'Fermi Gas' specifically for this question.