# Negative chemical potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chemical potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/chemical-potential)

The chemical potential of electron and positron is equal but with opposite  sign. How one can visualize the negative chemical potential of positron, physically?