# What’s the basic procedure to draw a QCD phase diagram?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, quark-gluon-plasma, heavy-ion

Could someone recommend a book/resource  where I can find a detailed way of sketching out a QCD temperature-chemical potential phase diagram using gap equations (eg. equations 35-37 or 39-40 as given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3907))?

P.S- Other similar questions on QCD phase diagrams focus more on their characteristics and not so much much on the basic method of obtaining them.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27033/226902

Answer (score 2):

It is rather a complicated question and still an area of active research.
The most reliable and direct way to plot the phase diagram with the axes $\mu, B, T$,
where $\mu$ is baryon potential, $B$ is magnetic field is by means of **Lattice QCD**.

However, there is a important limitation - that the theory with baryon chemical potential suffers from notorious *sign problem*. This makes the direct simulation not feasible and results are obtained with imaginary chemical potential $i \mu$, and then analytically continued to the real axis. There also exist different approaches for handling the sign problem - reweighting, complex Langevin, but none of the gives fully satisfactory results.

As a not very recent but of a good quality review I recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0701002v1.

Comment: thanks for sharing the paper. I am not looking for a "good" phase diagram, rather, how does one reach 'any' T-$\mu$ curve starting from gap equations (eg. equations 35-37 or 39-40 as given in [http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/~blaschke/maestro/B+AnnPhys2014.pdf]? The gap equations in principle have 2 unknowns - mass $m$ & $\triangle$ (for $\mu=0$) but how to plot the T-$\mu$ curve? So, I 'm not looking for the physics as much as the steps to sketch out a phase diagram.